# HTTP Status 500 Internal Server Error when I deloy web application on docker ec2

Tags: java, docker, web, amazon-ec2, jstl

When i try to deloy my web application using .war file on docker ubuntu aws ec2. I create container and assign the port to it. When I run it, I get the error 500 HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error. But when I execute it on eclipse, it works fine. The .war file I exported from the project followed this git hub link: https://github.com/vophucson/project-cloud
Please give me some advice

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the detail problem is: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: [org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV]